# What civilisation used wolf pelts for their archers armour?

Tags: war

Looking for more information on the negatives and positives of wolf pelt armor and many other general aspects. Thank you :)

Comment: Giants in Skyrim ;)

Comment: What leads you to believe that one did?

Comment: Vote to close unless OP provides some evidence that this is an actual historical event. Absent that evidence, this isn't really a question about history.

Comment: Welcome to our website. Please take a look at our FAQ and than try to change your question a bit, e.g. in this style: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/was-there-ever-any-organization-of-thieves-or-pickpockets as it's a nice example of a similar thing.

Comment: Ancient Rome. Bear and wolf pelts were worn by the standard bearers of century and cohort units.

[Link](http://www.legionxxiv.org/signum/)

Answer (score 1):

During the middle ages, wolfs were exterminated by law in most of Europe because they would destroy farms crops and livestock. This meant that their pelts were a dime a dozen and so a few landed on peoples back as clothes.

As to why it was used by archers, I have never read such a thing anywhere but in my personal opinion I highly doubt that archers would prefer wolf pelt because pelts are less flexible than materials like leather and to an archer flexibility and speed is very important.

Comment: belts == pelts? :)

Comment: @spyder Oops, my bad. Rookie mistake